# Centos 7 -ERROR: Error installing rails: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, centos7

I got this error message when trying to install Rails on Centos 7

```
[root@xxxxx ~]# sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get Nokogiri installed on CentOS and RHEL seems to be the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) which contains a prebuilt nokogiri package. To use it, install the appropriate [epel-release](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) package for your OS, then run:

```
sudo yum install -y rubygem-nokogiri
```

If you have issues, make sure you have some of the basic Ruby developer tools that you’ll need to compile the C extension, `libxml2`, and `libxslt`:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel zlib-devel
```